# MySQL compound aggregates and incorrect syntax?

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I've been trying to run a simple compound query for a few hours now and have check at least 10 different SO questions about this same topic. Everything I try fails and the only feedback the client I'm forced to used to run my queries says is Incorrect MySQL Syntax.

This query works just fine:

```
         SELECT JobClass, COUNT(EmployeeID)  
         FROM Employees 
         GROUP BY JobClass;
```

We are trying to find the JobClass with the least number of employees. This displays a table of all the JobClasses and the number of Employees in each, but I need to display just JobClass with the minimum number of employees.

Can anyone help me understand why this doesn't work, despite all of interwebs telling me it should?

Comment: Create an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) please.

Comment: Good – so now you can see a more detailed error message when you try and execute your second query in that environment. And that should be easy enough to research and fix.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get what you want rather than trying to use a subselect.

```
SELECT
    JobClass,
    COUNT(EmployeeID) as employeeCount
FROM Employees
GROUP BY JobClass
ORDER BY employeeCount ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @phyremynd That is pretty basic SQL stuff (much more basic than trying to use subselects), you should familiarize yourself with it.